# Problem with parent child communication in angular 6

Tags: angular, parent-child

I have a problem with an parent/child communication in angular 6, the code working. However I get an error in karma. Refer to below:

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'choices' since it isn't a known property of 'app-display-show-choices'.
1. If 'app-display-show-choices' is an Angular component and it has 'choices' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-display-show-choices' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'menu'">
      <app-display-show-choices      
       [ERROR ->][choices]="displayView.choices"
       (nextView)="onNextView($event)"
       >
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/DisplayViewComponent.html@5:7
'app-display-show-choices' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-display-show-choices' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-display-show-choices' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
  <div [ngSwitch]="displayView.type" >
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'menu'">
      [ERROR ->]<app-display-show-choices      
       [choices]="displayView.choices"
       (nextView)="onNextView("): ng:///DynamicTestModule/DisplayViewComponent.html@4:6
Can't bind to 'choices' since it isn't a known property of 'app-display-show-choices'.
1. If 'app-display-show-choices' is an Angular component and it has 'choices' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-display-show-choices' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'choice'">
          <app-display-show-choices         
           [ERROR ->][choices]="displayView.choices"
           (nextView)="onNextView($event)"
           >
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/DisplayViewComponent.html@12:11
'app-display-show-choices' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-display-show-choices' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-display-show-choices' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
      </div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'choice'">
          [ERROR ->]<app-display-show-choices         
           [choices]="displayView.choices"
           (nextView)=""): ng:///DynamicTestModule/DisplayViewComponent.html@11:10
```

The parent component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { DisplayView } from '../../model/display-view.model';
import { Choice } from '../../model/choice.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-display-view',
  templateUrl: './display-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display-view.component.css']
})
export class DisplayViewComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {

  @Input() displayView: DisplayView;
  choices: [Choice];
  @Output() nextView = new EventEmitter<number>();


  @Input() currentView: number;
  hidden: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.hidden = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.hidden = !this.displayView.isFirst;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if ( this.currentView !== this.displayView.id) {
      this.hidden = true;
    } else {
      this.hidden = false;
    }
  }

  onNextView(nextView: number) {
    if ( nextView !== this.displayView.id) {
      this.hidden = true;
    } else {
      this.hidden = false;
    }
    this.nextView.emit(nextView);
  }

}
```

parent html:

```
<div [hidden]="hidden">
  <h1>{{displayView.title}}</h1>
  <div [ngSwitch]="displayView.type" >
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'menu'">
      <app-display-show-choices      
       [choices]="displayView.choices"
       (nextView)="onNextView($event)"
       >
      </app-display-show-choices>
      </div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'choice'">
          <app-display-show-choices         
           [choices]="displayView.choices"
           (nextView)="onNextView($event)"
           >
          </app-display-show-choices>
    </div>
</div>
```

The child component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Choice } from '../../model/choice.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-display-show-choices',
  templateUrl: './display-show-choices.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display-show-choices.component.css']
})
export class DisplayShowChoicesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() choices: [Choice];
  @Output() nextView = new EventEmitter<number>();
  clicked: number;

  constructor() {  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick(choice: Choice) {
    this.clicked = choice.value;
    this.nextView.emit(choice.nextQuestion);
  }

}
```

App.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DisplayMainComponent } from './display/component/display-main/display-main.component';
import { DisplayShowChoicesComponent } from './display/component/display-show-choices/display-show-choices.component';
import { TerminalUserLogonComponent } from './display/component/terminal-user-logon/terminal-user-logon.component';
import { DisplayViewComponent } from './display/component/display-view/display-view.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DisplayMainComponent,
    DisplayShowChoicesComponent,
    TerminalUserLogonComponent,
    DisplayViewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

display-view.model.ts:

```
import { Choice } from './choice.model';


export class DisplayView {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    type: string;
    public isFirst: boolean;
    public choices: Choice[];

    constructor(values: Object = {}) {
        Object.assign(this, values);
      }
}
```

It is probably something quite stupid since I'm just starting with angular.In the project I have other parent child combinations that are oke. Please help me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please provide your `app.module.ts`

Comment: You need to add NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA property inside 'schemas' property.

Comment: I did try that, the same error appears when ng test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem causing this error. The spec file of the first parent component was missing the HttpClientModule and BrowserModule imports.
By adding those, it solved the error. However, I still don't understand why such error is given by missing those components in the main parent component test spec file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that `DisplayShowChoicesComponent` is in the `declaration` section of your corresponding `.modules` file that provides your `DisplayViewComponent`.

An example for a basic `HomeComponent` is:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Next thing you need to worry about is the input `@Input() choices: [Choice];`. I don't know this syntax. Can you try

```
@Input() choices: Choice[];
```

instead? Same above in the `DisplayViewComponent`'s `choices: [Choice];` - try `choices: Choice[];` instead.

Comment: I have added the app.module.ts file in the question, so you can see the component is defined. I have not created a seperate module. I have also changed the the syntaxt into choices: Choice[];, but still get the same error.